# Aggregate the elements of an array to not be larger than a defined value

Tags: c#, algorithm, aggregate

I have an array, say

`var myArray = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 7};`

I want to get a new list that stores the sum of the elements of this array in a way that when I add the first element to the next, it takes the result forward and then adds to the next etc., but if the sum result is greater than 6, it skips to the next element and starts a new sum but saves the previous sum to the new list.

So, for my array above, I am expecting a result like this
`6, 5, 6, 3, 7`

How do I go about this?

This is what I have tried. Problem here is that the last element is always skipped. I also worry if this is the perfect way to go about it.

```
int[] DoAggregate(int[] array)
{
    var prev = 0;
    bool first = true;
    var sum = 0;

    List<int> result = new();
    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum + prev;
            if ((sum + item) > 6)
            {
                result.Add(sum);
                sum = 0;
                prev = item;
                continue;
            }
        }
        prev = item;
        
    }
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You seem to have an algorithm written in text. What happened when you tried to implement it?

Comment: I'm using a foreach to loop through each elements, taking account of the previous, but it skips some of the elements when I add the greater than 6 condition.

Comment: Please show code (as an edit to your question, as text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all you need to do is take into account when `sum + prev` is a value greater than 0 after the loop:

```cs
int[] DoAggregate(int[] array)
{
    var prev = default(int);
    bool first = true;
    var sum = 0;

    List<int> result = new();
    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum + prev;
            if ((sum + item) > 6)
            {
                result.Add(sum);
                sum = 0;
                prev = item;
                continue;
            }
        }
        prev = item;
        
    }

    sum = sum + prev;
    if (sum > 0)
    {
        result.Add(sum);
    }
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. I looked through your edit history and tried those ones too, they worked.  Any reason why you deleted the other suggestion?

Comment: @IsaacIkusika I tested my solution against yours and for some situations got different results, so decided to leave just the fix to yours.